# Удаление Notification при остановке процесса

Tags: android, android-service, android-notification

Запускаю notification из Service. Потом в случае если приложение например крашится по идее вызывается OnDestroy, в котором я пытаюсь удалить notification, но почему-то оно остается в статус баре.

Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: Т.е. если не в onDestroy удалять, то работает?

Comment: А покажите как вы создаете  notification и как вы его уделяете!?

Comment: У меня плеер, который работает даже когда приложение свернуто. Соответственно пока он играет должно висеть notification.

После того как я нажимаю кнопку "последние приложения" и свайплю  его в сторону (окончательно закрываю) - плеер останавливается, но onDestroy уже был вызван когда я нажал "назад".

Comment: если приложение крашится, то `onDestroy` не вызывается

Comment: А что тогда вызывается? 
Может в классе Application что-то ?